# Need to stop cairo desktop popping up on start up

Tags: cairo-dock

There is a small window that pops up during start up. It is in the lower left hand corner of desktop on Ubuntu 13.10. It has a picture of an window that i have open and a #1 inside the window. Its approx. one inch in size. I can hit show desktop and it goes away. Im trying to get rid of it on startup.

Comment: upload the image on a image hosting site and edit your post.

Comment: You can simply hit <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and it should drop a screenshot in your `~/Pictures` folder. Edit your post, click on the little `img` button and upload the screenshot. More importantly, though, could you (before you make the window go away), type `xwininfo` in a terminal (your cursor will change), then click on that small small window you want to get rid of, and then paste the output that `xwininfo` wrote into your terminal here?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9bH2A.png)? Are you using [Cairo-Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/) or something?

Comment: you are correct. it does look like that. I do have cairo dock. just need to stop it from popping up when desktop opens. thanks again